# Using MACROS in printf that may be expanded to an integer or no value

Tags: c++, macros, printf, variadic-functions

I am writing some C++ code that makes use of the following macros:

```
#if(PRINT_DEBUG_SYMBOLS)
    #define FILE_NAME __FILE__
    #define LINE_NUMBER __LINE__
#else
    #define FILE_NAME ""
    #define LINE_NUMBER
```

I use these Macros in the following manner:

```
SendMsg(2000, "Unable to open file %s %d", FILE_NAME, LINE_NUMBER);
```

As you can see FILE_NAME is expanded to the name of the file or an empty string based on PRINT_DEBUG SYMBOLS. I want similar behavior with LINE__NUMBER. It should print the line number or no number based on PRINT_DEBUG_SYMBOLS. But there is no equivalent like empty string for an integer, so I am getting some random integer printed when PRINT_DEBUG_SYMBOLS=0. How do I solve this problem?

Here is the definition of SendMsg(). I don't have the flexibility to modify this function.

```
void SendMsg(int code, char* Msg, ...)
{
    char buffer[256];
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, Msg);
    vsprintf(buffer, Msg, args);
    ostringstream line;
    line<<code<<buffer;
    printf("%s", line.str);
}
```

Comment: Print a default integer constant? And don't add C tag for C++! These are **different** languages. Enable compiler warnings. Actually, your compiler should report an error.

Comment: And, why wouldn't, `#define`ing  `LINE_NUMBER` as `0`, work? The line number can't be 0 anyways, so you'll know that `PRINT_DEBUG_SYMBOLS` wasn't defined if you get `LINE_NUMBER` equal to 0.

Comment: No, I do not want to have a default integer constant. I want it to be blank.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius My aim is to implement an error reporting mechanism for a library tool. The error messages reported should contain the line numbers for the debug version, but should not contain any number for the release version. To have zeros printed on all error messages will be absurd for the client using the library.

Comment: @user2524261 Then, there's no way to do that. You need to alter your `printf`s to account for the values not being defined.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius I thought there could be a way if I modified the macros somehow. Like for example introduce a new macro that performs a string concatenation of the file name and line number (with the line number being converted to string somehow)

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius Or no need of concatenation. just being able to convert the integer to a string will do

Comment: @user2524261 I was thinking something along the lines (it will work only if your strings are in-code, and not got, for example, from a file, but you should, still, get an idea) of: `#define SendMsg_Whatever(code,message) SendMsg (code, message " %s %d", FILE_NAME, LINE_NUMBER);` in case the `PRINT_DEBUG_SYMBOLS` is defined, and `#define SendMsg_Whatever(code,message) SendMsg (code, message);` in case it isn't. And then, using `SendMsg_Whatever` in your code.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius message is a string that is composed of one or more variables (for example: "Unable to open file %s", Filename)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to `#define LINE_NUMBER 0` in the non-debugging case, and then use the format `%.d` instead of `%d`:

```
SendMsg(2000, "Unable to open file %s %.d", FILE_NAME, LINE_NUMBER);
```

That will cause a `0` to not be printed [see Note 1], although it will not suppress any space characters, so the output will still have two redundant space characters at the end of the message. Possibly you don't care about that.

If you know that `FILE_NAME` and `LINE_NUMBER` are both macros (or pseudo-macros like `__LINE__`) and that `LINE_NUMBER` is a literal number, then you could stringify and string concatenate to produce a single field:

```
#define STR_(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_(x)
#define FILE_LINE FILE_NAME " " STR_(LINE_NUMBER)

SendMsg(2000, "Unable to open file %s", FILE_LINE);
```

Or you could be more sophisticated and provide both format and value macros:

```
// FILE_NAME and LINE_NUMBER need to be defined at some point
#if(PRINT_DEBUG_SYMBOLS)
    #define FILE_LINE FILE_NAME, LINE_NUMBER
    #define FL_FMT "%s:%d"
#else
    #define FILE_LINE ""
    #define FL_FMT "%s"
#endif

// ...
SendMsg(2000, "Unable to open file " FL_FMT, FILE_LINE);
```

---

#### Notes:

1. Excerpt from the C11 standard, §7.21.6.1, which documents `*printf` formats:

   > …
   >
   > After the `%`, the following appear in sequence:
   >
   > … — An optional precision that gives the minimum number of digits to appear for the `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, and `X` conversions, …. The precision takes the form of a period (`.`) followed either by an asterisk `*` (described later) or by an optional decimal integer; if only the period is specified, the precision is taken as zero.
   >
   > …
   >
   > The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
   >
   > `d,i` The int argument is converted to signed decimal in the style `[−]dddd`. The precision specifies the minimum number of digits to appear; if the value being converted can be represented in fewer digits, it is expanded with leading zeros. The default precision is 1. The result of converting a zero value with a precision of zero is no characters.